# How to fix Undefined index warning in php

Tags: php

I get Notice: Undefined index: sesStatus warning and I am able to fix this warning when its just a variable, but this is part of a code and I am not sure how to fix the warning.

Her is the code that its doing it on.

```
case $_SESSION['sesStatus']=='e_logged':
    $cc_section = $cc_emp;
    $sidecol = $sc_employer;
    break;
```

Comment: isset() is your friend or make sure data is available in the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `case $_SESSION['sesStatus']=='e_logged':`

with

`case isset($_SESSION['sesStatus']) && $_SESSION['sesStatus']=='e_logged':`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all else is well, I'd start by testing for the existence of the key with isset().  Also, testing for equality in the `case` statement is unusual.

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['sesStatus'])) {
    switch($_SESSION['sesStatus']) {
        case 'e_logged':
            $cc_section = $cc_emp;
            $sidecol = $sc_employer;
            break;
    }
}
```